# XMLHttpRequest : Firefox Issue when "setRequestHeader"

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, zk

I have to set custom request headers for my ajax calls (POST).
As I'm behind a client/server framework ([ZK](http://zkoss.org)), I can't master the whole process (from open() to send()). That's why I can only set the request headers as follows, overriding native "onsomething" functions :

```
var zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr_OLD = zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr();
zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr = function() {
    var xhr = zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr_OLD ();
    xhr.onloadstart = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 1) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XX-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER", "foobarhimself");
      }
    }
};
```

This works very well using Chrome, but doesn't work at all on Firefox.
The point is that using Firefox, I only get ready state 4 when I put a breakpoint at the 'if' line. Using Chrome, my breakpoint stops successfully with `xhr.readyState` equal to '1' (`xhr.OPENED`), and xhr.readyState still equals 1 when executing `xhr.setRequestHeader(...)`.

And yet, both with Chrome and Firefox, `zk_native_function_to_create_a_xhr_OLD()` returns me an instance of XMLHttpRequest object (with same default attributes).

Both calls, ie. the `send()` on Chrome and on Firefox are made asynchronously.
To top it all, when I remove the breakpoint on firebug, my line `xhr.setRequestHeader` seems to be reached because when executed I get following error on console :

**InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable**

In my opinion, that's because at the time xhr.setRequestHeader() is called, xhr.readyState already equals '4'... Its value changes from 1 to 4 at the speed of life !

How can I resolve this issue ? Or is there another way I can call "xhr.setRequestHeader()", or in another "prototypable" onsomething handler ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just set the headers before send the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by directly overriding the native open() function, which happens to be called in the embedded framework.

```
var zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr_OLD = zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr();
zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr = function() {
  var xhr = zk_native_function_to_instanciate_a_xhr_OLD ();
  var xhr_open_base = xhr.open;
  // native XmlHttpRequest.open() signature from XmlHttpRequest API
  xhr.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
    xhr_open_base.apply(this, arguments);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("XX-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER", "foobarhimself");
  }
};
```